# SQL Server 'cross apply values' alternative in postgresql

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I've got a working sqlserver query with "cross apply values" that I need to port to postgresql. My current approach is an unattractive union all :-(
I've tried "unnest", but this does not allow me to keep the second column 'level' in my query. Anyone of you with a good idea?

WORKING SQLSERVER QUERY:

```
SELECT j.id, crossapplied.term, crossapplied.level
FROM job j
LEFT JOIN job_tag jt ON jt.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN job_employee_qualification jq ON jq.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN location loc ON loc.id = j.location
LEFT JOIN job_language jl ON jl.job_id = j.id
CROSS APPLY (
  VALUES (jt.tag_name,''),(jq.qualification_type,jq.level),(jl.language_name,jl.level_name),(j.company,''),(loc.city,''),(loc.country,'')
) crossapplied (term,level)
WHERE crossapplied.term <> ''
GROUP BY j.id, crossapplied.term, crossapplied.level;
```

And my current postgresql alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT j.id, jt.tag_name as term, null as level
  FROM job j
  LEFT JOIN job_tag jt ON jt.job_id = j.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT j.id, jq.qualification_type as term, jq.level as level 
  FROM job j
  LEFT JOIN job_employee_qualification jq ON jq.job_id = j.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT j.id, loc.country as term, null as level
  FROM job j
  LEFT JOIN location loc ON loc.id = j.location
  UNION ALL
  SELECT j.id, jl.language_name as term, jl.level_name as level
  FROM job j
  LEFT JOIN job_language jl ON jl.job_id = j.id
  ) data
  where term != ''
  GROUP BY id, term, level
```

The later does not really make sense in terms of performance, readability and compactness :-(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Martin

Comment: `cross apply` is Microsofts implementation of the standard `lateral join`. You should be able to simply replace `cross apply` with `cross join lateral`

Comment: Seems to me it's better to use CTE in both cases

Comment: Can you help me out with an example, I am really stuck here and was not able to find a suitable example on the web :-(

Comment: Ok, I've managed to get a structure like this:
`id  term  level  term  level  term  level`
But how can I now unpivot this to get
`id term level`
where the redundant columns are turned into rows?

Comment: Oh my goodness... the good things are so close. It's really just replacing APPLY with JOIN LATERAL. I really have to learn to think simpler :D Thanks horse!